# "Document is used" when opening Word Application

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I would like to copy a content form a docx to a txt file. I have the following issue:

after `$doc = $wd.Documents.Open($path)` is run a dialog box opens saying the document is already used. I have to manually select to open a read-only version, save the file as new file or get informed when the document is ready (standard Windows message) 
I dont have the file open.

I do have a solution for this: I run one line of code: `Get-Process -Name "*word*" | Stop-Process`

My question: I am sure there is a more elegant way to do this correctly, right? In my solution running the code would stop me from using any docx when running the script...

```
$path="C:\test\Test.docx"
$destination="C:\Test\File1.txt"

$wd = New-Object -COM 'Word.Application'

$doc = $wd.Documents.Open($path)

$content=$doc.Content.Text 

$doc.Close()

Set-Content -Path $destination -Value $content
```

Comment: The more elegant solution would be to figure out what is using the file. Perhaps your test code is leaving it open?

Comment: @DougMaurer Thanks for the hint! I havent thought so, cause of `$doc.Close()`, but then I figured out it is necessary to quit it with `wd.Quit().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have personally been bitten by word not fully letting go of my document. Double check it's not your test code that is causing the issue.

In addition to closing the document, also close the word instance.

`$wd.quit()`

Additionally you can force garbage collection.

`[System.GC]::Collect()`